# Formatting certain column and rows

Tags: python, format, row

I'm trying to figure out how to center align and do some number formatting on A2:A9 and C2:C9.  The header has it's own formatting.

I added this line of code but now I'm stuck on how to implement it on the columns/rows I need.

```
chain = wb3.add_format({'num_format': '###0+00.00','align': 'center'})`
```

[image]

Comment: try the following function with format being your `chain`: write(row, column, token, [format])

Comment: we need more of your code to answer this accurately. Are you using `openpyxl`? is `chain` your "A" column?

Comment: I figured chain could be added to any column that I wanted to format this way. Yes, openpyxl